# Proving that $\max(f(n),g(n)) = \Theta(f(n)+g(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

> Prove that for every two positive functions $f(n),g(n)$: $$ \max(f(n),g(n)) = \Theta(f(n)+g(n)). $$

---

I've just started data structures and I barely understand it, so please be gentle with me.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for math.se, the sister site on mathematics.

Comment: The task has nothing to do with data structures. What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Hint: apply the definitions.

Comment: what means $\Theta(f(n)+g(n))$?

Comment: @miracle173 Check [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you, but I know the definition, but I think it would be useful for the user and the post if it is added to the question. Especially if he reads YuvalFilmus' answer. It also would show some effort to solve the question.

Comment: @miracle173 I don't think there's any need to add completely standard definitions to the post.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I thinks for a user that is not very familiar with this topic (and I assume that this is the case here) it should be the first step when he tries to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the inequality
$$
\frac{a+b}{2} \leq \max(a,b) \leq a+b.
$$
To prove this, assume that $a \leq b$. You need to show that this implies that
$$
\frac{a+b}{2} \leq b \leq a+b.
$$

Comment: still don't get it. could you please explain it a bit more please

Comment: It's an exercise. Supplying a complete answer will ruin the point of the exercise. Try relating the definition of big $\Theta$ to what I wrote.